# Disable event listener set by external library

Tags: javascript

In some place of an external library (which, of course, I can't change), an event listener is created this way:

```
someElement.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    whatever();
});
```

I need to get rid of this listener or override it somehow. But it seems that it can't be done, as I don't have any way to reference the anonymous function used.

It's not necessary that this is the only listener removed. Removing **ALL** the `keydown` listeners would be also OK, if it were possible.

I've seen that an option would be cloning the element and replace it, but I can't do that, because there is a lot of initialization, and a lot of other events listeners are created. I just need to cancel the `keydown` one.

Is there anything I can do?

Comment: If you want the quick dirty solution, delete the element and then add it again dynamically.

Comment: @kemicofa Unless it's a delegated event

Comment: If you're able to sneak in some code before the external library runs, you can monkeypatch addEventListener to make it possible to find and remove them later: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31087882/3412322

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can listen for the event in the [*capture phase*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing) and stop its immediate propagation.

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input')
const log = () => console.log('I shouldnt log')

input.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  e.stopImmediatePropagation()
}, true)

input.addEventListener('keydown', log)
```

```html
<input placeholder="Type here"/>
```

Passing `true` as the [3rd parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Parameters) of `addEventListener` listens for the event on its capture phase (or an options object with `{ capture: true }`.

But that's assuming you have the chance to add this listener *before* the listener you want to disable and the element doesn't have any inline listeners.

Otherwise you can just wrap it into an element that follows the same concept:

```js
const disablers = document.querySelectorAll('[disable-event]')
const input = document.querySelector('input')
const log = () => console.log('I shouldnt log')

input.addEventListener('keydown', log)

disablers.forEach(disabler => {
  disabler.addEventListener(disabler.getAttribute('disable-event'), e => {
    e.stopPropagation()
  }, true)
})
```

```html
<span disable-event="keydown">
  <input onkeydown="log()" placeholder="Type here"/>
</span>
```

This stops the event propagation on the parent element so it never reaches
the element itself.

Comment: I accept this answer, because it's as far as it goes. This doesn't work for me, but it's the right answer. Thank you, Nik :-)